# What's the deal with Rebecca in the Cabin, in S1E9 of This is Us?

Tags: this-is-us

In Series 1 Episode 9 of "This is Us" - "The Trip" - Randall finds out that

> Rebecca has known about William for all of Randall's life, and that his mother hid that fact from him.

Later on in the episode, after Randall accidentally takes hallucinogens, he has a vision of

> his father, who implores him to look inside the cabin and "take a closer look". Randall sees a flashback of the Pearson family happily playing Monopoly, and on this "closer look", has a vision of his mother locking the cabin doors and screaming.

I was hoping this episode would be explained later on, because at the time this baffled me, but I've reached the end of Season 2 and am still none the wiser on what this meant.

Was the show suggesting that Rebecca had periodic mental breakdowns? Was Randall somehow witness to this and repressed the memory? Later on, Randall goes to confront his mother about the secret, and says that he imagines it was a very hard thing for her to keep the secret from him for 36 years. But I don't understand how this connects to the cabin. Was this scene really just a metaphor for the stress of keeping the secret?

If the answer is explained in Season 3 or onwards, please use spoiler tags appropriately, as I'm still watching the series.